# Meaning of word/title "Doodenbeer"

Tags: germanic-languages

The Fritz Mackensen painting titled Doodenbeer painted around 1900 has this unusual title. What does the title mean? I hear it might mean death beer, but this painting is about a funeral scenario and no beer is involved or seen in the painting.

Comment: It's definitely not 'beer'. It's something about the verb 'to bear' meaning 'to carry, to support': https://translate.google.com/#nl/en/beer

Comment: @YellowSky. What makes you think it is Dutch?  Fritz Mackensen was German.

Answer (score 3):

“Doodenbeer” is North German dialect (Plattdeutsch). Literally it does indeed mean “death beer”. It is a drink taken after a funeral, then, in a broader sense, a funeral ceremony or wake itself.

See the entries “Beer” and “Doodenbeer” here: http://neon.niederlandistik.fu-berlin.de/en/plattdeutsch/wb?buchstaben=B

Answer (score 0):

[The title means](http://www.akg-images.co.uk/archive/Doodenbeer-2UMDHUQZUE4T.html) "A wake in the house of the deceased", *beer* here means 'to bear, to support', and it's most probably the latter meaning which is relevant here.